# Audio recorder component

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, audio

I'm not really a AS/Flash developer, but I may need to develop one or two components. 
Specifically, I'm working with this component: https://github.com/cykod/FlashWavRecorder/tree/master/flash

This flash audio recorder works, but the only way to get the "recorder audio" is through its upload function. I mean, I can't get a byte array or an object which holds the recorder message and let my Javascript code do the upload.

The only option for this component is its own upload function. Yet I need to perform the upload through Javascript.

One reason I need to do it this way is because I need to process the Server response after the uploading of the audio has finished.

How can I get the audio directly from Flash to Javascript without uploading a file to the server?

Comment: I found a component that just fit the need: https://github.com/jwagener/recorder.js

Comment: I have got answer to my similar question.

[How to record audio and save it in mp3 format?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341945/how-to-record-audio-and-save-it-in-mp3-format-in-as3-adobe-air2-5

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the component that fits the need:

https://github.com/jwagener/recorder.js