# How to record audio and save it in mp3 format in AS3 (Adobe Air2.5)?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, mp3

I am building one desktop application in Air2.5, which needs to record and save audio.
In AS3 (Specially with Air 2.5), is it possible to record and save audio in **mp3** format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is library to convert audio to mp3 : 
https://github.com/kikko/Shine-MP3-Encoder-on-AS3-Alchemy

To record audio informations are here :
http://titansturf.in/2010/02/08/fetching-data-from-the-microhpone-and-recording-sound/

This also should be usefull :
http://suzhiyam.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/as3-microphone-record-and-save-as-wave-file/

And about save read this :
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html

Comment: The second link is dead. :( Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I use this pre-built Flash + JavaScript solution. It costs money, but works great. It will record, encode to MP3, and upload via PHP:
http://recorder.denniehoopingarner.com/

Here is a free related example that will use Flash to encode to OGG:
http://labs.byhook.com/2011/02/22/ogg-vorbis-encoder-decoder-for-flash/

I sat next to some Google programmers at a recent hackathon in SF who shared with me that Chrome will have the audio recording flag turned on by default starting April 2013 which technically makes recording in pure JS possible, but I have not seen a solution to encode and upload to a server yet. Good luck!

Comment: Rajneesh, if you have a code sample, I'd love to play around with your code if it's an open project. I'm also looking for a simple way to record in Windows and upload to a server. Your solution seems like a good one. I'm brian@epiphanet.com