# Can I record a sound channel in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

Would it be possible to record the audio of a sound channel and then store it in a MP3 format? I know it is possible to use a SoundStream to dynamically stream the audio played and record it at the same time, but could I record a sound channel?

Comment: Yup, I've been trying to accomplish this with my own app. You can extract the audio into bytes, but my problem is I don't know how to determine the start point and end point of the audio to extract. If that makes any sense xD

Comment: You can get the audio bytes.
You can encode it to wav
Converting it to mp3 is something I couldn't do when I tried 2 years ago

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your question: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/create-a-useful-audio-recorder-app-in-actionscript-3/

Skip down to the code part. I'm not totally sure about the .mp3 (you probably have to install a third-party codec, but don't quote me...), but saving it as a .wav is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a similar question and i got answer to it.

[Record and Save audio in mp3 format in AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341945/how-to-record-audio-and-save-it-in-mp3-format-in-as3-adobe-air2-5)

Best Luck.