# Recording internal audio with Flash/AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, record, piano

After searching the net high and low, I just cannot for the life of me figure this out. I'm definitely a newbie with all things Flash, but I'm teaching myself where I can. I've gotten a simple Flash piano working, and would like to add record & play back functions. This is where the problem comes in- I can find any multitude of answers for recording from the *microphone* and saving/playing it back with Flash, but the only things I can find relating to internal audio (or Flash-based pianos) at all are questions like this one with either really vague answers or just no answers at all.

I have some sort of idea that I should be creating an array that tracks the clicks? (It's a mouse-playable piano at the moment, but if it's better for me to make it keyboard-based, that's something I can do at least). After (before? during?) creating that array, how do I keep the rhythm/timing correct?

I'm just super lost and really need your expertise...

Comment: I have got answer to my similar question.

 [How to record audio and save it in .mp3 format?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341945/how-to-record-audio-and-save-it-in-mp3-format-in-as3-adobe-air2-5

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track in storing the clicks in an array. As far as rhythm and timing, when the user wants to start "recording" you can start a timer, I'd every 200ms or so. You can use that timer to determine at what point in time the key was clicked for use when playing it back.

I don't know if something like a long press is something you'd need, but to do that, with the same timer, you can set a start time and end time (press-->release) and just subtract the end time from the start time and now you have the duration of how long the key was pressed

**EDIT:** here is a quick example of what I was referring to in my original post: http://ronnieswietek.com/piano/piano_example.swf

the source: http://ronnieswietek.com/piano/piano_example.fla

Comment: So let's see if I can hammer this out in my brain- when they press record, a timer starts that checks every ~200ms for a click, and when there is a click, that gets pushed to the array, along with the time? Is there any way you could give me a rough example of what a line of code for that would look like? (And thank you for the long press! That's not something I was worrying about for now, but I did want to figure out how to add it later!)

Comment: The timer doesn't listen for clicks, you will use the timer to reference the current time..I'll whip up an example real quick

Comment: I edited my original answer to show a little example I made. It isn't perfect and it can probably be more efficient, but hopefully that will lead you in the right direction. I also put the timer down to every 10 milliseconds to make it more accurate

Comment: You are quite simply wonderful, "thank you" doesn't begin to cover it. Thank you!!