# Record AS MP3 or OGG flash

Tags: php, javascript, html, flash

Im searching for an audio recorder for my website , I have foudn some good recorder like WAMI and jRecorder , but both of them record as WAV format and can not record as MP3 format , I heard I have to encode them to mp3 in server side ,

so when I get 5 min record , I get 50 MB file which with MP3 or OGG that  could be 3-4 MB only .

do you have any idea or suggestion on encoding or recording into MP3 or OGG before sendign to server ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 rather simple solutions of your problem.

The first is a server converter-app. You can use FFmpeg, it will be really easy. If you already have a mediaserver (like Wowza or Red5) you can use it for this task, just read an official server guide, I think such a common question will be discribed in it.

The second is to use a Flash mp3 recorder app. I don't think you'll find a full ready one, but you can code it yourself (it's near 300 lines of code). [This information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341945/how-to-record-audio-and-save-it-in-mp3-format-in-as3-adobe-air2-5) may help you.

Comment: nice , even I find a link that do that . but it do not send to server , I have to contact creator for soure

Answer (score -1):

I use a program like Audacity to export .wav files as .mp3

Not sure how you'd convert your wav files on a server.