# record an x second silence audio file with byteArray and Adobe Air or Flex

Tags: apache-flex, audio, air, adobe

I need to record (without a microphone) a file with x amount of silence. For example, the user enters "5", then the program should record a file with 5 seconds of silence.

Comment: I edited your question to make it clearer. That being said, please post your attempt to solve this problem. SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341945/how-to-record-audio-and-save-it-in-mp3-format-in-as3-adobe-air2-5) but with some updates, in [this](http://suzhiyam.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/as3-microphone-record-and-save-as-wave-file/) link a code to record from mic, you need to simulate the mic, to do so in this function and write 0 instead of `sample`, do this each second:

```
function micSampleDataHandler(event:SampleDataEvent):void
{
    while (event.data.bytesAvailable)
    {
        var sample:Number = event.data.readFloat();
        soundBytes.writeFloat(sample);
    }
}
```

i never tried this but i think it will work, good luck.

Note: to convert output to mp3 have alook on the question above there is a library for that.